# Python: split linestring on vertex if vertex has more than 2 lines connecting it

Tags: python, gis, geopandas, shapely

I have a multilinestring object looking like [image: this]

I would like to split the line at the point where the line branches out [image: at this point]

I can't just convert the line to points for every vertex because the lines are not straight. So I need to be able to select the vertex that has more than 2 lines connecting it [image: (i.e. this vertex)], then do the split based on that.

However I haven't been able to discover anything on how to achieve this in Python, particularly the shapely/geopandas libraries. I have lots of lines like this hence my need to do it automatically.
I have had a glance at the multilinestring object itself but it has hundreds of lines within it and is hard to make sense of. but in theory 2+ lines joining each other would share the same vertex?

Thanks!

edit: in response to exploding the line- the line was already joined together by a unary union of numerous lines. exploding them simply undoes this. [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X385t.png)

Answer (score 1):

When you only apply `unary_union` on lines, it just collects all individual lines to a MultilineString without any other restructuring of the lines.

For lines, typically you also want to apply [shapely.line_merge](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.line_merge.html#shapely.line_merge). This will merge LineStrings to longer LineStrings when exactly 2 LineStrings touch in one point. If > 2 lines end in a single point, they will stay seperate LineStrings.

After `line_merge`, when you use [geopandas.explode](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.explode.html), you should +- get what you are looking for.

Sample script:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import shapely

# Prepare input
line = shapely.LineString([(-1, 0), (2, 0)])
multiline = shapely.MultiLineString([[(2, 0), (5, 0), (10, 10)], [(5, 0), (10, -10)]])
lines_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[line, multiline])

# Apply union + explode: touching lines stay seperate
lines_union = lines_gdf.unary_union
print(lines_union)
lines_union_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[lines_union]).explode(ignore_index=True)

# Apply union + line_merge + explode: touching lines are merged
lines_merged = shapely.line_merge(lines_gdf.unary_union)
print(lines_merged)
lines_merged_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[lines_merged]).explode(ignore_index=True)

# Plot
lines_gdf.plot(color=["orange", "red"])
lines_union_gdf.plot(color=["orange", "red", "green", "yellow"])
lines_merged_gdf.plot(color=["blue", "green", "yellow"])
plt.show()
```

Input sample data:

[image]

When only unary_union + explode is applied, the lines are seperated at the crossing, but the touching linestrings are not merged:

[image]

When unary_union + line_merge + explode are applied, the touching linestrings are properly merged and where lines cross, they are seperated:

[image]

Comment: unfortunately the line is made up of many lines- I joined them together with a unary_union. so exploding them just undo-s the unary union. I've added a picture to my original post. unless there is a way to better merge them altogether so that the multiline string is indeed only a few linestrings rather than all of them?

Comment: Unary_union doesn't really join lines. Please try [shapely.line_merge](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.line_merge.html#shapely.line_merge) instead.

Comment: yeah that was more along the lines of what I was after, not perfect but can't see any other way... thanks :)